# get height of absolute element with height auto

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have situation like here [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uqmctwh2/1/)

Was wondering how to get height of expanded child? Because now jquery `height()` gives me 0

Any suggestions or references.

Comment: Actually `.height()` should work. [It works fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/uqmctwh2/8/). The problem is that you are logging the height *before* the animation has started/finished and then the height is still 0.

Comment: Maybe you can provide fiddle link? Because here http://jsfiddle.net/uqmctwh2/10/ I have the situation I was describing.

Comment: I provided a link in my first comment.

Answer (score 2):

For what I realize, the problem is that you are running the animation and getting the height at the same time.

If you add a timeout equal to the animation time you get `90` as the result.

```
$( ".list-el" ).mouseover(function() {
  var b = $(".el-bottom");
    setTimeout(function () {
       alert(b.innerHeight());
    }, 1700)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

while you are trying to get the height of the child to correct the situation, there is a better way without js, i know it's not what you've been asked for but try to consider this...don't use js if you don't have too, try to make the page load easier and faster:

```
ul{
    list-style: none;
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.list{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}
.list-el{
    width: 100%;
    background: #ff00ff;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.el-top{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 75px;
}

.el-bottom{
    text-align: center;
    background: #f0fff0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    -moz-transition: 1s;
    transition: 1s;
}

.list-el:hover .el-bottom{
    max-height: 700px;
    height: 100%;
}

.list-el:hover .el-bottom{
    max-height: 700px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uqmctwh2/11/

Comment: While this may be a "good practice", it's absolutely irrelevant to OP's question. This answer would be better fit as a comment.

Comment: you right, but you can see what he is try to go for so he don't really needs to get the child's height to correct this, it's like the "x-y problem"...

Answer (score 0):

Try working with `.innerHeight()`