# add height to parent element of absolute positioned child on its expand

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-animations

I have this situation: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uqmctwh2/12/)

What I try to achieve is to push down the row of blocks that is underneath the expanded one.
At first I tried to use jquery to get and add height of expanded child to parent and that way to push down the lower row of blocks to achieve something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4w5g6.jpg, but on hover height() returns 0 and using delays would make animation look buggy.

Here's code:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <ul class="list">
        <li class="list-el">
            <div class="el-top">Expand 1</div>
            <div class="el-bottom">Cupcake liquorice cupcake sweet roll ice cream caramels. 
                Lollipop dragée chupa chups. Sugar plum candy jelly-o bonbon gummies caramels.
                Jelly icing tiramisu candy chupa chups chocolate bar. 
                Sweet pastry jelly-o marshmallow jelly lollipop pie marshmallow cookie. 
                Lollipop sugar plum lollipop jelly lollipop pudding. 
                Tart jelly-o gummi bears sweet roll gummi bears.
                Jelly icing tiramisu candy chupa chups chocolate bar. 
                Sweet pastry jelly-o marshmallow jelly lollipop pie marshmallow cookie. 
                Lollipop sugar plum lollipop jelly lollipop pudding. 
                Tart jelly-o gummi bears sweet roll gummi bears.
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list-el">
            <div class="el-top">Expand 2</div>
            <div class="el-bottom">Lollipop sugar plum lollipop jelly lollipop pudding. 
                Tart jelly-o gummi bears sweet roll gummi bears.
                Jelly icing tiramisu candy chupa chups chocolate bar. 
                Sweet pastry jelly-o marshmallow jelly lollipop pie marshmallow cookie. 
                Lollipop sugar plum lollipop jelly lollipop pudding. 
                Tart jelly-o gummi bears sweet roll gummi bears.
                Jelly icing tiramisu candy chupa chups chocolate bar. 
                Sweet pastry jelly-o marshmallow jelly lollipop pie marshmallow cookie. 
                Lollipop sugar plum lollipop jelly lollipop pudding. 
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list-el">
            <div class="el-top">Expand 3</div>
            <div class="el-bottom">Cupcake liquorice cupcake sweet roll ice cream caramels. 
                Lollipop dragée chupa chups. Sugar plum candy jelly-o bonbon gummies caramels.
                Jelly icing tiramisu candy chupa chups chocolate bar. 
                Sweet pastry jelly-o marshmallow jelly lollipop pie marshmallow cookie. 
                Lollipop sugar plum lollipop jelly lollipop pudding. 
                Tart jelly-o gummi bears sweet roll gummi bears.
                Jelly icing tiramisu candy chupa chups chocolate bar. 
                Sweet pastry jelly-o marshmallow jelly lollipop pie marshmallow cookie. 
                Lollipop sugar plum lollipop jelly lollipop pudding. 
                Tart jelly-o gummi bears sweet roll gummi bears.
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list-el">
            <div class="el-top">Expand 4</div>
            <div class="el-bottom">Lollipop sugar plum lollipop jelly lollipop pudding. 
                Tart jelly-o gummi bears sweet roll gummi bears.
                Jelly icing tiramisu candy chupa chups chocolate bar. 
                Sweet pastry jelly-o marshmallow jelly lollipop pie marshmallow cookie. 
                Lollipop sugar plum lollipop jelly lollipop pudding. 
                Tart jelly-o gummi bears sweet roll gummi bears.
                Jelly icing tiramisu candy chupa chups chocolate bar. 
                Sweet pastry jelly-o marshmallow jelly lollipop pie marshmallow cookie. 
                Lollipop sugar plum lollipop jelly lollipop pudding. 
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
ul{
    list-style: none;
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.list{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}
.list-el{
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    background: #ff00ff;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.el-top{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 75px;
}

.el-bottom{
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 1.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: max-height 1.5s ease;
    transition: max-height 1.5s ease;
    position: absolute;
    background: #f0fff0;
    top: auto;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.list-el:hover .el-bottom{
    display: block;
    max-height: 700px;
}
```

Maybe someone has some ideas how to solve this? Would appreciate it very much.

Comment: The solutions suggested on [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29848050/get-height-of-absolute-element-with-height-auto) are addressing the same issue, just I missed my mark on what I am trying to achieve therefore question was not really covering the actual question and as none of the answers suited the situation I updated the question to have more clear view. As there the question asks for solutions to how to get height, but misses the fact how and why I will use it, therefore the solutions of that questions doesn't really fit for this one.

Comment: Virtual duplicate of [get height of absolute element with height auto](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29848050/get-height-of-absolute-element-with-height-auto)

Comment: Similar, but not the same question.